# Oil pump failure

Tags: gasket-maker

How likely is an oil pump failure from instant gasket residue in the sump? Main bearings seized.

I'm seing the remains of the innards of the oil pump, but also small bits of red sticky goo in the sump of a diesel Transit, and i know there was a shed load of red gasket sealant used on the timing cover, as it kept getting leaks, and wouldnt seal properly.

The lower half of the oil pump strainer was loose in the sump with the strainer, where it possibly blew off the pump. Could that have been caused by a blockage?

The van has been pulling a huge amount of loads, so probably more that, but just wondering about anyone elses thoughts on gasket sealant and oil pump failure?

Comment: Can you add a photo of the bits in the sump?

Comment: Why do you think the oil pump has failed ?

Answer (score 1):

If the pick-up tube of the oil pump has come off, then the oil pump wouldn’t have been able to pickup any oil.  Without oil getting to the pump, all other damage would be explained.

I can’t see how a blockage would cause the strainer to “blow off”.

How is the oil strainer meant to fasten on?

Did you continue to drive with the oil light on?

Comment: it's not my vehicle, or job, just trying to figure out, which happened first.